# Exchange calendar syncs to Android, but not to Google

Tags: sync, 4.4-kitkat, calendar, exchange

I feel as though I am missing a simple configuration change on my Android device.  I recently setup my work Exchange account on my Galaxy S4.  My calendar entries from Exchange show up on my Android calendar just fine.  However, I want those entries to actually get pushed to my Google calendar.

Is there an easy way to have my Android device push those events to my Google calendar instead of keeping them local to the phone calendar itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sync 'droid with Outlook](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/78758/sync-droid-with-outlook)

Comment: @Chahk I don't think that question is related. The person who asked that question wasn't using Exchange at all, and wanted Outlook on a PC synced with a Google calendar.

Comment: @DanHulme The solution is the same though. Unfortunately neither Google nor Microsoft provide a way to integrate their calendars with each other. In order to have a true sync (not just see both entries in Android's calendar app) you have to use a 3rd-party software running on your Windows machine. [Related recent article on the subject](http://blogs.wsj.com/personal-technology/2014/07/15/syncing-microsoft-outlook-and-google-calendar-a-guide-to-the-nightmare/)

Comment: @Chahk The dupe suggestion is the reverse of what the user wants. I've shared a possible solution, but I can't test it because of security policies in our company.

Answer (score 0):

Share the ICS URL of your Exchange to Google Calendar.

From an [Oregon State University HOWTO](http://oregonstate.edu/helpdocs/faq/how-do-i-export-my-outlook-exchange-calendar-my-google-calendar):

1. Click on `Calendar` in the lower left corner
2. You should see all your calendars in front of you. On the left side of the window, you should see the list of calendars and their names. Under My Calendars, right click the one you wish to add to your Google account.
3. After right clicking your chosen calendar, right click, go `Share > Publish This Calendar (Publish This Calendar to the Internet)`
4. A new window will pop up. Select the options for which best suit you.
5. When complete, press `Start Publishing` in the lower right corner.
6. A couple of urls will show up for you to copy. Find the one that ends in .ics and copy that whole url.
7. Go to [Google Calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar/)
8. When logged in to view your calendar, go find `Other Calendars` on the left side of the window
9. After finding Other Calendars, there should be a box with `a triangle` in it to the right of the text. Click that box and find `Add by URL`.
10. A popup will show up. In this popup, you want insert the .ics URL from your Outlook here.
11. Press `Add Calendar` below.